# Calling an async function inside of a if/else statement - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I wonder if I making any mistake here.

```
 let id;
    if (window.location.hash.slice(0, 1) === '#') {
      id = window.location.hash.slice(1);
      console.log(id);
      await model.loadRecipe(id);
    } else {
      id = window.location.hash.slice(0);
      await model.loadRecipe2(id);
    }
```

Only when the else statement is returned, i get the id 'undefined'.

Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: if `window.location.hash.slice(0, 1) !== '#'` then it's likely that `window.location.hash === ""` so your call is effectively `await model.loadRecipe2("");` - what does `model.loadRecipe2` do with an empty string? surprised that `id` is `undefined` though, since `window.location.hash` is a string, so no matter how you `.slice` it, the result will be a string

Comment: As Bravo said, the hash is empty string: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hash
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWPOE.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWPOE.png) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hash#specifications
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9Xfz.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9Xfz.png)

Comment: "when the else statement is returned, i get the id 'undefined'": how are you determining this? Is there a console.log statement that you haven't included in the example?